# Elasticsearch Range greater than or field does not exist

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

So the problem is something like this I want to get posts that whose `online` field is greater than a time or the field does not exist and I only want to use these two clauses as a filtering mechanism i.e. they should not contribute any score towards the search and there are other clauses that do the actual searching.

Here is what I currently have

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {"range" : {"online" : {"gte" : time}}},
                {"bool": {"must_not": {"exists": {"field": "online"}}}}
            ],
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I think these are contributing to the score. If a doc where the online field is greater than time it gets a score of 1.0 and if there is a doc where the online field is not present it gets a score of 0.0

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your [`bool should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query inside the bool `filter` clause. In the `filter` clause the scoring is ignored, so the score from the `range` or `should` will not contribute any score towards the search. Modify your query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "range": {
                "online": {
                  "gte": 6
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "online"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Nilan Saha please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?